# Azureリソースマネージャでストレージのコンテナ作成

Tags: azure, powershell

リソースマネージャからストレージ内にコンテナを作る方法は
無いでしょうか？
スクリプトを作りたいのですが、コマンドも見当たらず困っています。

Answer (score 3):

ARM用のコマンドの中に直接的な操作を行うものは今のところなさそうです。
ただ操作そのもののAPIは変わらないのでこちらの方法でできないでしょうか。

http://statemachine.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/04/01/103532

ストレージのContextさえできれば何とかなるかと思います。

Comment: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/08/02/deploying-blob-containers-with-arm-templates/ こんな感じでARMテンプレート内でコンテナ生成できそうです